# Can't get python requests to work with proxies

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to do a simple get request through a proxy server:

```
import requests
test=requests.get("http://google.com", proxies={"http": "112.5.254.30:80"})
print test.text
```

The address of the proxy server in the code is just from some freely available proxy lists on the internet. The point is that this same proxy server works when I use it from browser, but it doesn't work from this program. And i tried many different proxy servers and none of them works through above code.

Here is what I get for this proxy server:

> ### The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> While trying to retrieve the URL: http:///
>
> The following error was encountered:
>
> > Unable to determine IP address from host name for
>
> The dnsserver returned:
>
> > Invalid hostname
>
> This means that:   The cache was not able to resolve the
>   hostname presented in the URL.   Check if the address is correct.

Comment: Are you sure it is port 80?

Comment: @Nick yes, it works for me in browser (Opera). You can test it yourself.

Comment: Try comparing both requests with wireshark.

Comment: Your exact code worked for me.  Try updating `requests`.

Comment: @jdotjdot I downloaded this version today, it is the last version of requests.

Comment: I will try to monitor network with microsoft network analyzer, maybe i can figure something out.

Comment: What's the version of requests?

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question, but it should be

```
import requests
test=requests.get("http://google.com", proxies={"http":"http://112.5.254.30:80","https": "http://112.5.254.30:80"})

print (test.text)
```

Comment: But that is not working with venv