# Http proxy works with urllib.urlopen, but not with requests.get

Tags: python, proxy, python-2.7, urllib, python-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t get python requests to work with proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146787/cant-get-python-requests-to-work-with-proxies)

The following code works perfectly:

```
f=urllib.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/headers", proxies={'http':"http://username:pass@ip:port"})
print f.read()
f.close()
```

However when I try to do the same with requests, it fails:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
auth=HTTPProxyAuth("username","pass")
test=requests.get("http://httpbin.org/headers",proxies={"http":"ip:port"}, auth=auth)
print test.text
```

This returns(apparently from the proxy server) the following response:

> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> ### 503 Service Unavailable
>
> #### Recursion
>   detected

Why?

Comment: You already asked about this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146787/). Please delete this duplicate.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost This is not duplicate. The error that is returned is different, and in this question I am using proxy with authorization required.